# Use IDEA Run/Debug Configuration to debug Gradle web app with Jetty plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, web-applications, jetty

## What's the problem?

Is it possible to debug a **Gradle** web app running via **Jetty** plugin (using `jettyRun` or `jettyRunWar`) by using a **IntelliJ IDEA** Run/Debug Configuration?

I know that it is possible (I've done it before) to do it with **Maven**/**Tomcat7** plugin and creating a simple Maven Run/Debug Configuration with the `clean package tomcat7:run` goals.

I've tried to create a Gradle Run/Debug Configuration with the `clean jettyRunWar` tasks. If I *Run* the configuration, everything works well. But the *Debug* option is not working as expected: the application actually runs, but debugger won't connect.

However, I did manage to debug the project by running on debug mode externally, like this:

```
$ export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n"
$ ./gradlew clean jettyRunWar
```

And then creating a Remote Run/Degug Configuration with all the default configurations except the port, which was set to `9999`.

But that's not the solution I was looking for. I want to be able to debug the project by only clicking a button. Am I missing something?

## Not in the mood to read everything? Here's an example

I've created a simple **IDEA**/**Gradle**/**Jetty** web app using **Jersey** available on Github [here](https://github.com/gabrielhuff/gradle-webapp). The problem can be reproduced by:

1. Cloning the repository
2. Importing it on IDEA
3. Creating a Gradle Run/Debug Configuration for the root project with the `clean jettyRunWar` tasks
4. Debug using the configuration

The debugger won't connect and breakpoints won't work.

I am using:

- **IntelliJ IDEA** Community Edition 2016.1.3 (OS X)
- **Gradle** 2.7 (a wrapper is available on the Git repository, so it doesn't matter)